# How to convert an array of datetimes to a list of specific date format

Tags: python, dataframe

my present array is given below:

```
 print(alldates)
```

Its output:

```
array([datetime.date(2019, 1, 25), datetime.date(2019, 1, 26),
       datetime.date(2019, 1, 27), datetime.date(2019, 1, 29),
       datetime.date(2019, 1, 31), datetime.date(2019, 2, 1)], dtype=object)
```

I want to convert it to something like this:

```
alldates = ['2019-01-25'.....,'2019-02-01']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `.astype(str)`:

```
print(alldates.astype(str))
```

Which outputs:

```
['2019-01-25' '2019-01-26' '2019-01-27' '2019-01-29' '2019-01-31'
 '2019-02-01']
```

Comment: Hi, could you take a look at this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70954791/identifying-statistical-outliers-with-pandas-groupby-and-reduce-rows-into-diffe

Answer (score 0):

you can use str() transfer to string and then append to new array

```
import datetime

alldates=[datetime.date(2019, 1, 25), datetime.date(2019, 1, 26),datetime.date(2019, 1, 27), datetime.date(2019, 1, 29),datetime.date(2019, 1, 31), datetime.date(2019, 2, 1)]

new_allldates = []
for item in alldates:
    new_allldates.append(str(item))

print(new_allldates)
```

Result:

['2019-01-25', '2019-01-26', '2019-01-27', '2019-01-29', '2019-01-31', '2019-02-01']

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result by using below code,

```
datelist = [datetime.date(2019, 1, 25), datetime.date(2019, 1, 26),datetime.date(2019, 1, 27), datetime.date(2019, 1, 29),datetime.date(2019, 1, 31), datetime.date(2019, 2, 1)]

resultlist = [i.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') for i in datelist]

print(resultlist)
```

**Result :**

['25-01-2019', '26-01-2019', '27-01-2019', '29-01-2019', '31-01-2019', '01-02-2019']